# When can we describe something 'as a function of' $x$?

Tags: functions

At a point $x$ in a functions domain we have $f(x)$, and we can write $y=f(x)$ and say '$y$ is a function of $x$', but what if I have a case where the space of values that $y$ can take differs from just the values that can depend on $x$? For example, if I have a function $f(x,y)$ and determine the values on a parametric curve $x=cos(t)$ and $y=sin(t)$

I can say that for *some* not *all* values of $x$ that $x=cos(t)$ and $y=sin(t)$, I can therefore say that $x=g(t)$ for some values of $x$ but not all, is allowable to say that $x$ is a function of $t$ along this curve or is it better just to say they have the same values?

Explicitly, I may want to determine the line integral of $f(x,y)$

We have the two relations, $f(x,y)=xy$ (for example) but also have a parametric curve that I wish to determine the integral on, $f(x,y)$ and $x$,$y$ are to take any values, but under certain conditions my $x$ and $y$ values may fall on my curve C, lets say its given by $C (t)= [cos(t),sin(t)]$

Let $D_1$ be a subset of $D$, the domain of $f$, we then have for $(x,y)$ in $D_1$ $x=c_1=cos(t)$ and $y=c_2=sin(t)$

Therefore $x=cos(t)$ and $y=sin(t)$ only for $x,y$ in $D_1$, and not for all $x,y$ in our domain of discourse, Can we say that as $x$ and $y$ can be expressed as $g(t)$ and $h(t)$ e.g. $x=g(t)$ and $y=h(t)$ that $x$ and $y$ are functions of $t$ along $C$ or in $D_1$?

Comment: A function is defined as a set of value pairs.  Some other set that shares some properties with a function but diverges in some ways is not a function...

Comment: Check your text, "form some not all values of..." you mean "FOR some not all values of ..."

Comment: You can't say "x=g(t) for some values of x ", because x is the dependent variable. That would be grammarly incorrect. It is a little like causality, x results as such, when t assumes that value. It's a conception of the interplay of dependent and independent variables.

Comment: This is too vague.  Depending on the context, you can certainly say that some set of points is *approximated* by some function.  Though it is not clear to me that this is what you intend.  Perhaps it would help if you gave a clear, explicit example of the situation you are considering.

Comment: You may be considering the distinction between the codomain of a function and the image of a function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to well understand your question, but, if $z=f(x,y)=xy$ is a given function  and you want to restrict its domain to the set $(x,y)=(\cos t, \sin t)$ for $0\le t<2\pi$, you can do it, and the result is a curve in the space with parametric equation
$$
(x,y,z)=(\cos t, \sin t, \cos t \sin t) \qquad 0\le t <2\pi
$$
that  has this graph:

[image]
And you can think this curve as a function of $t$:
$$
F:[0,2\pi)\to \mathbb R^3 \qquad F(t)=(\cos t, \sin t, \cos t \sin t)
$$

Comment: This makes sense, my main question is essentially this, can I define the values in the domain, on the parametric curve as an expression in terms of their respective values of $t$, would doing this mean that I can only have $x$ taking values on the curve? Or can I think of the curve as a smaller set on values that $x$ can take? If so can I say that those values of $x$ map to $t$ as a function?